# Mass Theory $\sigma$ - Algebra of Set system consisting of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: analysis, statistics

## Question

$\Omega = \mathbb{N}$ and *M* is a system of sets that consist of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ and their complements. Determine whether M is an Algebra and a $\sigma$- algebra

## What I know

I know that in order for a system of sets to be an Algebra then $\Omega$ must be an element of the system. If A and B are elements of the system then their union also has to be an element of the system of sets. Also if A is an element of the system of sets then its complement must be an element of the system. Also $\emptyset \in M$ must also be an element.

In my case we know that $\Omega$ is an element of the system *M* and also we know that the finite subsets lets say $A_i \in \mathbb{N}, i=1....n$ are elements of the system and their complements as well. Im quessing since $\Omega = \mathbb{N}$  then all the unions of $A_i$ are also elements of the system M. My question is then, I'm i right so far? Also how do i know that the empty set is also part of my system and if there are only a finite number of subsets in the system M does that mean its not possible for it to be a $\sigma$-Algebra. Since $\sigma$-Algebra is different from Algebra in the sense that if there are infinet subsets $A_i$ then$$\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$$ is also an element of the system and its complement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collection of finite and cofinite sets is indeed an algebra. However by proving that it is irrelevant that $\Omega=\mathbb N$.

That the collection is closed under complements is evident.

If $A,B$ are finite sets the so is $A\cup B$ and if one of the sets is cofinite then so is $A\cup B$.

The empty set will be an element of the collection simply because the empty set is finite.

Further the collection is not a $\sigma$-algebra. This because every set $\{2n\}$ (where $n$ denotes a positive integer) will be an element of the collection, but the union of these sets, i.e. the set of even numbers is not finite and is not cofinite.

If $M$ is an algebra and only contains a finite number of sets, then automatically it is a $\sigma$-algebra. This because any union $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$ where the $A_i$ are elements of $M$ can also be written as $\bigcup_{i\in S}A_i$ where $S$ is a *finite* subset of $\{1,2,\dots\}$. Then $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\in M$ because $M$ as algebra is closed under finite unions.

Comment: @drhabThank you for answering the question. The only thing that confuses me a little is where you said $$\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$$ can be written as $$\cup_{i\in S}A_i$$. Do you mean for example at S=1 there is an infinite union $$\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$$ and S is a finite subset? Sorry Im not understanding what it represents.

Comment: If $M$ is finite and $A_i\in M$ for $i=1,2,\dots$ then $\{A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots\}$ is a finite set. If it contains e.g. $k$ elements then there are indices $i_1,\dots,i_k$ such that $\{A_1,A_2,\dots\}=\{A_{i_1},\dots, A_{i_k}\}$. Then we have $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i=A_{i_1}\cup\cdots\cup A_{i_k}$. In this context $S=\{i_1,\dots, i_k\}$.